# TreeView Selected node value with sql query

Tags: sql, treeview

I have this sql query

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM GPS1_MAP where sta_id=" & TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value, con)
```

and the treeview code is here

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateDataBindings="False" Font-Names="Arial"
                        Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="#C04000">
                        <Nodes>
                            <asp:TreeNode Text="Paties">
                                <asp:TreeNode Text="CHENAB COTTON MILLS" Value="CHENAB COTTON MILLS"></asp:TreeNode>
                                <asp:TreeNode Text="AJMER COTTON GINNERS" Value="AJMER COTTON GINNERS"></asp:TreeNode>
                            </asp:TreeNode>
                        </Nodes>
                    </asp:TreeView>
```

But its not working with slected value of tree what may the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Value` of your select node (eg. `<asp:TreeNode Text="CHENAB COTTON MILLS" Value="CHENAB COTTON MILLS"></asp:TreeNode>`) is the string `CHENAB COTTON MILLS`.

Therefore your SQL statement will become:

```
SELECT * FROM GPS1_MAP where sta_id=CHENAB COTTON MILLS
```

Notice that there are no quotes around `CHENAB COTTON MILLS`. Your statement will therefore not be valid.

You could either add quotes around the value, such as:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM GPS1_MAP where sta_id='" & TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value & "'", con)
```

Or use [named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx), which is a better solution (since it prevents SQL injection attacks).

Comment: Sir Is this possible to populate Tree View from the Database if u have any idea or link then tell me

Comment: @user1103342 Check this article: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx

Comment: This hava a lot of code i dnt understand what part of code to use please tell any simple way to do this